# Is there a way to achieve a "mergeXml" processor in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm working on a flow where I take an XML document, use the splitXML processor to split it into multiple files.  I then call some other processors to manipulate/duplicate some of that data for a poc to generate dummy data.  Ultimately I would like to merge all those split/duplicated flowfiles back into one xml again, but I'm not seeing  any kind of mergeXML (which seems understandable as splitting is easier than putting humpty dumpty back together).

Do any NIFI gurus out there have any suggestions on a good way to accomplish this?  I see mergeContent processor, but I'm not quite sure how/if that could get me what I need.  Any tips are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use mergeContent where you could define header, delimiter, and footer.